# How can I use a variable that is defined in the razor page, in a C# cs file in a Blazor project?

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have a Blazor project where I want to pass a variable from the razor page to a C# cs file in the project. I know how to proceed for the reverse case. I mean I can use the variable from the related cs file as @varible in the razor page. But how to proceed in my case?

Comment: _I can use the variable from the related cs file as @varible in the razor page_. Are you referring to a .cs file, or a .razor.cs file?

Comment: I want to pass the variable to a .cs file, but if it's easier i could also pass it to the related razor.cs file and then call it from the .cs file. I use a common .cs file for common variables. Therefor I want to pass.

Comment: We probably need more information about the content of this .cs file and its purpose (service, data model ...).

Comment: On the razor page (connect.razor) the user types an IP adress into an input field  from the machine, he wants get some data. This IP adress is stored in a variable in the code path of the razor page. On the other side There is .cs file (Wmi.razor.cs) where data is read with WMI from the remote machines. The IP addresses from the razor file should be used in this cs file for the connection

Comment: So the .cs file is some kind of service? Then, you could inject the service, and call one of its method having the IP address as a parameter.

Comment: Data and data management doesn't belong in components, it belongs in DI Services.  `Connect` injects the `WMI` service.  It calls something like `GetInfo(string ipAddress)` on the service and then displays the data retrieved into say the `DeviceInfo` property in the WMI service.  However, without more code and information to go on I'd be shooting in the dark with an answer!